# SwiftUI 4 how can I show video selected from gallery

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am using the new SwiftUI. 4.0 for IOS 16 Beta . I am using the new photo picker and can see both images and videos in the gallery . Once I select an image I can display it on the view but not sure how I can do the same for Videos . Any suggestions would be great since I am practicing . This is my code ...

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
    @State var data: Data?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            
            if let data = data, let uiimage = UIImage(data: data) {
                Image(uiImage: uiimage)
                    .resizable()
            }
            
            PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItems,
                         maxSelectionCount: 1,
                         matching: .any(of: [.images,.videos])) {
                Text("Pick Photo")
            }.onChange(of: selectedItems) { newItem in
                guard let item = selectedItems.first else {
                    return
                }
                item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        if let data = data {
                            self.data = data
                        } else {
                            print("data is nil")
                        }
                    case .failure(let failure):
                        print("Failed: \(failure)")
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }

        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For videos you should get an `URL`, you must decode the data, get the `URL` then use `VideoPlayer` to display the video:

```
@State var url: URL?
 ...
if let url {
    VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
}
```

I'm not sure for the decoding part as I haven't tried it yet, but first try to load an `URL`, then load `Data`. Now create a `String` from that `Data`, finally set the url.

Answer (score -2):

[developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708061)

You can use this link

transform movie and get URL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).